# Error 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'

Tags: python

I have df4, which is data from 1st jan-26th Aug. df5 is this data from 1st Jan - 28th Feb, I'm trying to create boxplot to display my data for each season. Here is my code. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

```
df5 = df4[pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2020', end = '28/02/2020')]
print(df5)
df5.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

sorry about the layout, I am new to this website. Each space is separated by a line.

Comment: Try `df5.plot.box()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df5 = df4[pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2020', end = '28/02/2020')]
print(df5)
df5.plot.boxplot()
plt.show()
```